# “Shut up” figurative/metaphorical form.

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> - Shut up

I heard a lot of native speakers saying this phrasal verb with their friends. But what I noticed, though, was that they didn’t mean it literally.

What meaning does it give when it doesn’t mean to **stop talking”?

Comment: People can say, *I shut up shop*, meaning that they closed their store. But they wouldn't mean that if they used *only* those two words.

Answer (score 1):

For this AmE speaker, amongst friends, "shut up" could be used to indicate incredulity with what someone had said. For example:

- Friend: You'll never believe who I saw buying a frappuccino at Starbucks today.
- Me: Who?
- Friend: Justin Bieber!
- Me: Shut up!
- Friend: No, really! He got it with 2% milk.

In this case, I would be indicating surprise that my friend had seen Justin Bieber in the flesh.